# Avoid blocking method to make the code asynchronous

Tags: java, asynchronous, client-server

How can I change this code to get rid of thread blocking? Here `.get()` blocks the thread to receive the result from the future. But can I absolutely avoid blocking? Something like - one thread sends the requests, and the other one receives responses and implements some code. To make it fully asynchronous.

I tried to use CompletableFuture, but couldn't really understand it.
Tried to make a callback method, but wasn't successful as well.

```java
byte[] sendRequest(JSONObject jsonObject, String username, String password) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

          try (AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient()) {
            String userPassword;
            if (username != null && password != null) {
                userPassword = username + ":" + password;
            } else {
                throw new NullPointerException("Нет логина и/или пароля.");
            }

            Future future = client.preparePost(apiUrl)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userPassword.getBytes()))
                    .setBody(jsonObject.toString().getBytes())
                    .execute(getHandler());

            String response = (String) future.get();
            return response.getBytes();
        }

    }

    private AsyncCompletionHandler<String> getHandler() throws IOException {
        return new AsyncCompletionHandler<String>() {
            @Override
            public String onCompleted(Response response) throws IOException {
                return response.getResponseBody();
            }

            @Override
            public void onThrowable(Throwable t) {
            }
        };
    }
```

**What I expect:**

1. The program sends a request in the main thread.
2. Then there is a kind of a callback that waits for a response in an
   alternative thread.
3. Still, the program continues working in the main thread - it goes on with sending more requests.
4. When the response from the server comes, the callback from the
   alternative thread catches it and processes in some way, but it
   doesn't correspond with the main thread

Answer (score 0):

You should run your async task in new thread (preferably using ExecutorService or CompletableFuture). Pass CallbackHandler to the Runnable/Callable tasks and once the invocation is complete invoke handler methods.

*Alternatively, if all you're worried about is handling async http requests, I'd suggest to not reinvent the wheel and instead use existing solutions. [Example of async http client](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.ws.rs.client.InvocationCallback)*

For other use cases, you can follow the following example.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            new Thread(new MyRunnable(new CallbackHandler())).start();
        }
    }

    static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        CallbackHandler handler;

        public MyRunnable(CallbackHandler handler) {
            this.handler = handler;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch(Exception e) {
            } finally {
                Random r = new Random();
                if (r.nextBoolean()) {
                    handler.onSuccess();
                } else {
                    handler.onError();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class CallbackHandler {
        public void onSuccess() {
            System.out.println("Success");
        }

        public void onError() {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```